# Very Thin purple line on monitor after Windows 7 updates

Tags: windows-7, display

yesterday I bought a Dell Studio XPS desktop with a 20" AOC monitor.  I got it all setup and running fine, and last night began transferring files/installing software etc.

This morning, I went to continue and there were some critical Windows 7 updates waiting to be installed, I installed them and restarted the computer when requested but when it restarted there is now a very thin, vertical purple line running down the monitor a few inches from the left.

I have tried rolling back the system to the prior to the updates, but the line is still there.

anyone experienced this or have any ideas how to resolve?  it has an ATI HD 5450 graphics card.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen a thin purple line on a colleagues laptop, but this was a hardware issue. It occurred after another colleague rather cack-handedly opened the lid of the laptop and banged it against the desktop monitor.
To isolate the problem from being graphics card related I would try another monitor connected to your hardware.

I would then also try your monitor on another computer that has been verified to have no graphics issues.

If the purple line appears on the screen while the monitor is connected to another computer, then the issue is with your monitor.

If the purple line is still 'on your computer' with a new monitor then the problem is with your hardware or software, and you can dig deeper knowing that.

Comment: Thanks! i had seen this advice on google several times, but because I appeared straight after the Windows update I was positivie that the update must have affected my drivers.. tried the monitor on my laptop and exactly the same problem - so turns out it was just the monitor

Comment: For anyone else coming here. This can happen suddenly. I alt-tabbed out of a game and that caused the purple line for me. It still shows up in the bios, so I know it's hardware. I think it's just a case of random stress for the monitor.